# Java: jumbled word program

Tags: java

My program loads two text files: one with a list of English words, another with jumbled words (more just random strings but most make words), then determines what words can be made of the jumbled ones and prints (at least supposed to) the word with its jumbled version next to it. My program effectively finds what words the jumbled words can make up. The problem is not all the words with jumbled equivalents print jumbled word next to them. Also I need the jumbled words on the right unscrambled on the right. Example here's some output (commas separate lines ie if two words in comma they were printed next to each other ; 
addej, 
ahicryrhe hierarchy, 
alvan naval, 
annaab banana, 
baltoc, 
braney nearby,

```
   public class Lab4{

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length<2) {
            Error(); }
        BufferedReader jumbledW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
        BufferedReader words = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        List<String> jumbledWList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> wList = new ArrayList<>();

        long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(jumbledW.ready()){
            String jumble = jumbledW.readLine();
            jumbledWList.add(jumble);
        }

        Collections.sort(jumbledWList);
        while (words.ready()){
            String word = words.readLine();
            wList.add(word);
        }
        Collections.sort(wList);
        for (String jumble : jumbledWList ) {
            System.out.print(jumble + " ");
            for (String word : wList) {
                if(toConnical(jumble).equals(toConnical(word)))
                    System.out.print(word);


        }
        System.out.println();   
        }
        long finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = finalTime - initialTime;
        System.out.println("The time taken for this program to run is " + time/1000.0 + " seconds" );

        }

    private static void Error(){
        System.out.println("\nError:You have to pass the name of the input files on the command line" );
        System.exit(0);
        }   

    private static String toConnical(String word){
        char [] arr = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        String connical = new String(arr);
        return connical;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your program; it looks at least on the right track to me.  Question: How are you supposed to be handling whtiespace, e.g. is `a hat` equivalent to `haat`, or does the space also have to be taken into account?

Comment: The statement is somewhat unclear in terms of input you provide and output you desire.

Comment: Tim only complete strings are grouped together so no 'a hat' isnt equivalent to 'haat'. Null the program is given a txt file of a great deal of english words youd find in a dictionary and another txt file with jumbled words such as cra which could make car or rat. The output i desire is the in reference to the example of cra would be "car cra" (on one line).

Answer (score 0):

While skipping through old unanswered posts I had come across this particular question which quite frankly is somewhat unclear as to what the actual problem may be. The way I read the post is this:

1. A file name is passed to this application through the command line which consists of several jumbled character words. Not certain however whether each line within the file consists of single jumbled words **OR** each line within the file consists of multiple jumbled words separated with one or more white-spaces (or perhaps even tabs). With this in mind we need to cover either scenario.
2. Yet another file name is also passed to this application through the command line which consists of several ***valid language type*** words. This file is to be considered the **Word List** to whereas any single jumbled word could pertain to one (***or more***) of those words within the list if it were unscrambled or not (the word within the Jumbled String list might not be jumbled).
3. As the **Jumbled String** list is processed each **Word List** word that is found to be capable of matching via sorted character to character comparison to the sorted Jumbled word characters is printed to console window.
4. Console output required is to be a comma delimited string consisting of each jumbled word followed by space delimited matching words from the Word List:

   **addej jaded, ahicryrhe hierarchy, alvan alvan naval, annaab banana,...etc**

   This is however appears to now be contradictory to your comment:

   > "the program is given a txt file of a great deal of english words youd
   >   find in a dictionary and another txt file with jumbled words such as
   >   cra which could make car or **rat**. The output i desire is the in
   >   reference to the example of cra would be "car cra" (on one line)."

   Whereas space delimited Word List words are to come first then the jumbled word processed each consuming a single console window line. Which format is desired? By the way **rat** can not be achieved from **cra**.

In reality your code works as expected however since you are using a **BufferedReader** object and a **FileReader** object your code will need to be in a **try/catch** block to handle any exceptions such as the **FileNotFoundException** and the **IOException**. This is a requiremnt and can not be excluded.

Below is your code slightly modified to accommodate your first desired output format:

```
try {
    BufferedReader jumbledW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
    BufferedReader words = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    List<String> jumbledWList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> wList = new ArrayList<>();

    long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (jumbledW.ready()) {
        String jumble = jumbledW.readLine();
        jumbledWList.add(jumble);
    }

    Collections.sort(jumbledWList);
    while (words.ready()) {
        String word = words.readLine();
        wList.add(word);
    }
    Collections.sort(wList);

    String resultString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jumbledWList.size(); i++){
        String jumble = jumbledWList.get(i);
        resultString+= jumble + ":";
        for (String word : wList) {
            if (toConnical(jumble).equals(toConnical(word))) {
                resultString+= " " + word;
            }
        }
        if (i != (jumbledWList.size()-1)) { resultString+= ", "; }
    }
    System.out.println(resultString);

    long finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = finalTime - initialTime;
    System.out.println("The time taken for this program to run is " + time / 1000.0 + " seconds");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

The jumbled word list file contained the following jumbled strings:

```
addej
ahicryrhe
alvan
annaab
baltoc
braney
cra
htis
```

the console output looked like this after running the above list of jumbled words across my 370,101 word Word List file. It took 0.740 seconds to process on my system:

```
addej: jaded, ahicryrhe: hierarchy, alvan: alvan naval, annaab: banana, baltoc: cobalt, braney: barney nearby, cra: arc car, htis: hist hits isth shit sith this tshi
```

All words shown above were in my Word List file.